# How to automatically install updates for specific packages?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I would like to know how to automatically install updates (silently) for specific applications without even having the need to start any GUI manually i.e. silently installing the updates like in Windows.

Comment: That makes no sense, as you want to " automatically install updates (silently) using Synaptic...", "without even having the need to start Synaptic".

Comment: i mean the synaptic package manager window (gui)

Comment: why "using synaptic"? why not just set it at the preferences of "software updates" and let it install using whatever that uses?

Comment: only specific packages (apps)?

Comment: He is interested in auto-update without GUI intervention. Synaptic is not the main Issue i guess. So, I've edited the question. See if it is what you wanted